# Adding a Calculated field in O365 Excel in VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

Task: I have a series of sheets for each employee. I can successfully add a pivot table calculating their total hours worked per month. I drop the Date field and autogroup it and add the sum of the hours. Works great. Now I want to add the calculated field of total number of business hours in each month. Here is the code:

```
    ' Define the data range for the pivot table
    lastRow = newWs.Cells(newWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = newWs.Cells(1, newWs.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set pivotRange = newWs.Range(newWs.Cells(1, 1), newWs.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    
           ' Create pivot table after the data in the new worksheet
            Set pivotTable = newWs.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pivotRange), TableDestination:=newWs.Cells(2, lastCol + 2), TableName:="PivotTable" & newWs.Name)
            
            ' Set up the Pivot Table
            With pivotTable
                .ColumnGrand = True
                .HasAutoFormat = True
                .DisplayErrorString = False
                .DisplayNullString = True
                .EnableDrilldown = True
                .ErrorString = ""
                .MergeLabels = False
                .NullString = ""
                .PageFieldOrder = 2
                .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RowGrand = True
                .SaveData = True
                .PrintTitles = False
                .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
                .TotalsAnnotation = False
                .CompactRowIndent = 1
                .InGridDropZones = False
                .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
                .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
                .DisplayContextTooltips = True
                .ShowDrillIndicators = True
                .PrintDrillIndicators = False
                .AllowMultipleFilters = False
                .SortUsingCustomLists = True
                .FieldListSortAscending = False
                .ShowValuesRow = False
                .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
                .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
            End With
            
            
            ' Refresh the pivot table
            pivotTable.RefreshTable
            
            ' Add the "Sum of Hours" field to the pivot table
            With pivotTable.PivotFields("Date")
                .Orientation = xlRowField
                .Position = 1
                .AutoGroup
            End With
            
            ' Add the "Sum of Hours" field to the pivot table
            With pivotTable.PivotFields("Hours")
                .Orientation = xlDataField
                .Function = xlSum
                .NumberFormat = "0.00"
                .Name = "Sum of Hours"
            End With
```

**              With pivotTable
.CalculatedFields.Add "BusHrs", "=IF('Hours'>0, NETWORKDAYS.INTL([Date], EOMONTH([Date], 0), 1) * 8, 0)"
.PivotFields("BusHrs").Orientation = xlDataField
End With**

The offending code is the last block in bold. it says it is Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable Class as a error 1004. I just want to to add a column in the pivot table that says "Oh, for Jan there were 160 business hrs". Right now, I can't get to to add ANY calculated field (even just ="1+1"....not even examples from Microsfot docs.

What do the Microsoft gods want from me??

TL;DR: Tried adding a calculated field and expected to have to debug my formula. I can't get it to accept ANY kind of calculated field. I am using the current (as of May 2023 of O365 Excel Desktop)

Comment: What code is produced when you try using the macro recorder?